# how to set the value to scale property for the resizable image in ios?

Tags: ios

how to set the value to scale property for the resizable image in ios?

```
- (IBAction)changeToLdpi:(id)sender
{


    myImage= [myImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 150,50,150) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
    //self.scale=2.0;
   CIImage *scaledImg=[[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:myImage];


   myImage=[UIImage imageWithCIImage:scaledImg scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];


    [self->imageView setImage:myImage];



//[_view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

i have used this code.
but the scale :2.0 is not working.
suggest me how to do tis?

Comment: is it possible you're looking for **[UIScreen mainScreen].scale**

Answer (score 0):

use this method it works

```
 myImage= [myImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 150,50,150)];

  UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[myImage CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
```

Comment: Be aware that Apple is releasing devices with **scale of three** very soon.  All fixed references to scale will break at that time.